# Blackberry using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, blackberry

I am using Eclipse for BlackBerry development. I cannot find how to see the log files.

Can anyone tell me how to see errorlog file in Eclipse for Blackberry development?

Answer (score 2):

To view the Eclipse error log:

Switch to the Plug-in Development perspective.
In the Tasks view, in the bottom right pane, click the Error Log tab.
The error log is displayed, showing the following information for each error:
The status of the error (for example, error or warning)
A brief description of the error
From which plug-in the error derived
The date and time that the error was produced
If an error has a plus sign (+) at the start of it, it is a complex problem, and there are a number of errors contributing to it. Click the plus sign to view the individual errors.

To see the details of a particular problem, double-click the entry in the Tasks view. A separate window is displayed, showing more details of the error.

Comment: hai i want to see log file line by line for example:system.out.println() in JDE

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see System.out.println output in Eclipse Console, you just have to start the Blackberry Device Simulator in Debug Mode as stated [here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/System-out-println-Eclipse-Simulator/td-p/20753).

Just right click in your project, select "Debug As" and then "Blackberry Simulator"